# mysqli bind_param does not set $stmt->error or $stmt->errno

Tags: php, mysqli

According to the php manual you can retrieve errors in any prepared statement method by interrogating $stmt->error and $stmt->errno however the bind_param method never seems to set these on an error, can anyone else confirm this? or tell me what I am missing please?

For example:

```
echo "Start\n";
$db = new mysqli('localhost','test','xxxxxx','test');

$val = 1;

$st = $db->prepare('insert into tblTest set field1=?');
if($st == false)
{
    printf("prepare: %s %d\n",$db->error,$st->errno);
}

$rs = $st->bind_param('is', $val);
if($rs == false)
{
    printf("bind_param: %s %d\n",$st->error,$st->errno);
}

$rs = $st->execute();
if($rs == false)
{
    printf("execute: %s %d\n",$st->error,$st->errno);
}

$rs = $st->close();
if($rs == false)
{
    printf("close: %s %d\n",$st->error,$st->errno);
}
echo "Finish\n";
```

Running the above from the command line displays:

```
Start
PHP Warning:  mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in test.php on line 14
bind_param: 0
execute: No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement 2031
Finish
```

So php is seeing this as a Warning, bind_param is returning false, but error & errno are not set. execute is also failing and has correctly set error & errno

Is this a bug?

Comment: Is it documented as doing anything else than returning false when it fails?

Comment: The PHP manual for mysql_error states that $stmt->error returns an "error message for the most recently invoked statement function that can succeed or fail". I would argue that a call to bind_param is the most recently invoked statement function that failed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`MySQLi::error` and `MySQLi::errno` are containers for error codes and messages returned by the RDBMS to PHP, *not* for errors encountered in the PHP code when setting up the statement.  An incorrect call to `bind_param()` (with insufficient parameters) does apparently not communicate with the RDBMS, and thus won't receive its error from the RDBMS.

According [to the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php), `bind_param()` returns a boolean `FALSE` on failure. So you will need to verify that it was called successfully.

```
$rs = $st->bind_param('is', $val);
if ($rs) {
  $st->execute();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I do indeed use the return value from bind_param in my code, the class I am building then throws an Exception to indicate something failed, but it would be useful to have a meaningful error returned in the exception, rather than just "bind_param failed" or whatever. The PHP manual is misleading as it states that $stmt->error returns an "error message for the most recently invoked statement function that can succeed or fail".

Comment: @user1508636 Yes I would agree that is a little misleading in the docs, but unfortunately you would need some custom PHP error handler to spin these PHP call errors together with the MySQLi errors.