# Preventing SQL Injection in Login Page in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a login page (`login.php`) and below is the code I am trying to use to authenticate the user by using `mysqli_prepare`:

```
if(!$_POST["username"] || !$_POST["password"])
{
    echo "Username and Password fields are mandatory.";
}
else
{
    $unsafe_username = $_POST["username"];
    $unsafe_password = md5($_POST["password"]);
    $query=mysqli_prepare($con, "select user_id from users where user_name= ? and password= ? ");
    $query->bind_param("ss", $unsafe_username, $unsafe_password);
    $query->execute();
    $data = $query->get_result();

    if(is_array($data))
    {
       echo "Login successful";
    }
    else
    {
       echo "Login failed";
    }
}
```

Below is the code used for making MYSQL connection:

```
function connect_database()
{
    $con = mysqli_connect("servername", "username", "", "dbname");
    if (!$con) 
    {
        $con = "";
        echo("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    return $con;
}
```

By using `mysqli_prepare`, I am getting following warning and error messages:

```
Warning: mysqli_prepare() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given

Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam() on null
```

I asked the similar question two days ago, but did not get any complete solution. ([Prevent SQL Injection to Login Page in PHP and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38278594/prevent-sql-injection-to-login-page-in-php-and-mysql)).

Please help me in resolving the problem. Is it the best approach to prevent my DB from SQL Injection?

Comment: You have to supply the second argument to `mysqli_prepare()` like so: `mysqli_prepare($connection,"SELECT * FROM table");`.

Comment: missing connection variable $query=mysqli_prepare($con,"select user_id from users where user_name= ? and password= ? ");

Comment: Mixing `mysqli with PDO` at `bindParam`

Comment: Please actually read the manual and see the examples: http://php.net/mysqli_prepare

Comment: Was typing this as you deleted your question just now: Since this site is live, add a new column to this table called `hash_type`, and then set it to `md5` for all rows. Change the size of the `password` column to be big enough to store newer hashtypes (e.g. varchar(128)). Then, as users log in, dynamically change their hash type to the new format - a nice easy way to get users to re-hash their accounts.

Comment: You asked a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38307263) that you delete around now, seem to still be struggling with security. For a login routine with modern hashing, see this for [mysqli](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33665819) and this one for [pdo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32556010) and good luck

Comment: You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure) and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. Make sure  you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

missing connection variable `$con`

```
$query=mysqli_prepare($con,"select user_id from users where user_name= ? and 
password= ? ");
```

and change this too

```
$query->bind_Param("ss", $unsafe_username, $unsafe_password);
           ^^^
```

Comment: By making your change, now I am getting this error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::bindParam()

Comment: @KPJ I'm not sure where you get your information from, but you seem to be doing piecemeal mix-and-matching between different database APIs. mysqli indeed has nothing called `bindParam`. It *does* have something called `bind_param`. Again, you should actually read the manual and stick to the examples shown there: http://php.net/mysqli_prepare

Comment: i updated my answers try it now @KPJoy

Comment: @jothi - I am getting no error now, but not able to login. My query is right, username and password are also in database but even then its not working. What am I missing now?

Comment: did you set up display_errors=on  in php.ini file ?

Comment: @jothi - Yes. I am checking for is_array. I think that is wrong. I have updated my question with exact syntax.

Comment: $data = $query->get_result(); 
  $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data);
  if(is_array($data))
  {
     echo "Login successful";
  }
  else
  {
     echo "Login failed";
  }                          add this line @KPJoy

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `$con` variable in the prepare function

`$query=mysqli_prepare($con,"SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_name= ? AND password= ? ");`

Answer (score 1):

The procedural style of `mysqli_prepare` expects the first parameter to be the connection variable and second one to be the string (query).

Change

```
mysqli_prepare("select user_id from users where user_name= ? and password= ? ");
```

to

```
mysqli_prepare($conn, "select user_id from users where user_name= ? and password= ? ");
```

Read [documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).