# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean

Tags: php, mysql

I'm fairly new to PHP and I know this is a well known problem, however I wasn't able to fix it though. 
According to the mysql log the connection to the database is established and immediately closed.

I attached the code snipped below, thanks for any help. Btw, this error occurs only on the "real" server, using XAMPP I got no problems at all...

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT UID FROM USERS WHERE username = ? and password = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $g_usernameSql, $g_pwSql);
```

Comment: place `var_dump($stmt);` after first line, what do you see?

Comment: try $rs= $stmt->bind_param("ss", $g_usernameSql, $g_pwSql);if ($rs) { $stmt ->execute();}

Comment: @olegsv it prints false

Comment: view this , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11374672/mysqli-bind-param-does-not-set-stmt-error-or-stmt-errno

Comment: You seem to have a problem with database connection. What is your code to connect with DB? Try to enable  exception throwing after connection and see:

`    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Answer (score 0):

Probable cause is: $conn->prepare is returning false because it is failing.

the $stmt is false and not a statement object. you should check if ($stmt === false) before using it.

Now to see why it failed check the array returned by $conn->errorInfo()
(presuming $conn is a PDO instance)

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT UID FROM USERS WHERE username = ? and password = ?");
if ($stmt === false) {
   var_dump($conn->errorInfo());
} else {
   // do stuff
}
```